# Can all curves be parametrised?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In my current multivariable calculus course, the definition of a line integral over a vector field has been stated as:

$$ \int_C {\bf F} \cdot d{\bf r} = \int_0^1 {\bf F}({\bf r}(t)) \cdot {\bf r}'(t)  dt $$

Where $t$ is a parametrization of the curve $C$ such that the end points of C correspond to t=0 and t=1 respectively. Of course, a line integral over a scalar field has a similar definition.

This naturally leads me to ask the question, can any curve in $\mathbb R^n$ be parametrised in term of one variable? Are there any requirements to be able to parametrise? Does the curve have to be differentiable? Smooth?

Perhaps a better question might be, how do we define a curve in $\mathbb R^n$? (I feel like this was poorly defined in our course.) Do we define it in terms of a parametrisation? Or is it a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ that satisfies certain properties - continuity, "connectedness"?

Comment: The question of how a 'curve' is defined is the central issue.  One way to define it can be any map $\varphi: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, or putting additional properties (that the image is a linear continuum).  Here (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Curve.html) has other definitions.  Ultimately, from the definition presented in this, it is a continuous map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is clearly parametrizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hypothesis that you define a curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in terms of parameterization is exactly right: a curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is normally defined either as a continuous function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}^n$ where $X$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $X$ is a closed interval, or as the image in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of such a function (that is, the curve is defined as the function itself or the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that the function yields as outputs).

Sometimes, one requires a curve to satisfy certain differentiability properties.  The details get very technical, but as an extreme example of how much it can matter, there is actually a continuous function from the unit interval onto the entire unit square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve), so the unit square is a curve according to the definition just based on continuity.

At any rate, by definition of a curve, there's no problem describing any curve as being given by a function of one variable.   But the space filling curve illustrates that the curve has to be differentiable, not necessarily everywhere (you can still talk about a line integral if there's one corner in the curve), but at least often enough, for this definition of the line integral to make sense.

There are a few other details to worry about also: for instance, if a curve is differentiable everywhere, but the derivative is really strange, the integral given in the definition may not make sense.

By the way, I'm not sure if you've taken any analysis, but here are some true facts: the words "continuous" and "connected" have formal definitions, the real line and any closed interval in the real line are connected, and continuous functions map connected sets to connected sets.  So yes, curves (or their images) do have to be connected.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've taken enough analysis to know the definition of continuous, and not enough to know connected (though I have seen it a few times exterior to my course, I just wasn't sure if I was using it correctly). I have actually seen the space filling curve before, it was one of the reasons I thought to post the question. Is it impossible to do a line integral on this kind of curve then?

Comment: I doubt there's any reasonable way to do line integrals on the space-filling curve.  I remember hearing something about ways to generalize the definition of line integrals so that it a) doesn't specifically refer to differentiability but b) still agrees with the "ordinary" definition of line integrals for functions where this definition makes sense.  But I don't know anything specific about those generalizations, and I would be surprised if they were able to make sense of line integrals on space-filling curves.